# Error C1083: How do I fix my broken Visual Studio compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

My Visual Studio always fails to compile any C++ program. I have not tampered or modified the compiler.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Gives Output:

```
1>Program
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'C:\Program': No such file or directory
1>Files
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Files': No such file or directory
1>Microsoft
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '(x86)\Microsoft': No such file or directory
1>Visual
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Visual': No such file or directory
1>x64
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64': No such file or directory
1>test.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>Done building project "test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I think that one of the paths is missing double quotes but I don't  know where to fix this.

Comment: how do you invoke the compiler? Can you show the command that is used to call the compiler?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `.vcxproj`? Since the compiler outputs these messages I'd bet on a `<ClCompile>` soup rather than a compiler path issue.

Comment: The person who allowed spaces in file names needs a robust talking to.

Comment: It takes much effort to cause MSVC to fail in this way. It looks like you've been messing with PATH and/or environment variables, or you have a CMake project which is broken/invalid. The best course of action is to undo all your changes to the environment, reboot and start with a new MSVC project. Also you might want to upgrade to MSVC 2019.

Comment: Looks like somewhere quote characters are missing (or has been removed) since some path was spited by spaces. This is quite unusual since this path points to standard library binaries.

Comment: Sounds a lot like [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66111173/why-visual-studio-2019-is-getting-error-c1083-like-if-the-spaces-between-the-pat#comment116884751_66111173) yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could check if the following path settings are correct.

1. Windows Settings->Advanced system settings->Environment Varibles->Path->Environment variable
   [image]
2. Visual Studio Project->Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories

[image]

If it still doesn't work, you could reset the `Environment Varibles` in `Tools->Import and Export Settings->Reset all settings`.